# Get threads from specific forum category in Django view

Tags: python, django

This is my current code.

```py
class TopicView(ListView):
    model               = Thread
    template_name       = 'forum/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    paginate_by         = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Thread.objects.order_by('-date_posted')
```

It is supposed to get threads only from the specific forum topic, but it instead gets all threads that are in the database. I have tried a few things to fix it but none of those fixes seemed to work.

**EDIT:** The models.

```py
class Topic(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug        = models.SlugField(default='test')
    description = models.TextField()
    icon        = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Thread(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    content     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic       = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pinned      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    locked      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    censored    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deleted     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_ip     = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def num_replies(self):
        return max(0, self.post_set.count() - 1)

    def last_reply(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by('-created')[0]
```

Comment: well you have to provide us with Thread and Topic models to fully anwser your question - we can't guess your implementation of relation

Comment: @quqa123 Edited the post and added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter by the given topic, so:

```
class TopicView(ListView):
    model               = Thread
    template_name       = 'forum/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    paginate_by         = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.filter(
            topic_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        ).order_by('-date_posted')
```

By setting [**`allow_empty`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.allow_empty) on `True`, it will return a 404 in case no `Thread` matches this topic (this is also the case if the `Topic` simply does not exists):

```
class TopicView(ListView):
    model               = Thread
    template_name       = 'forum/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    paginate_by         = 5
    allow_empty         = True  # 404 if empty

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.filter(
            topic_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        ).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work, but now it does not return a error 404 if the forum topic does not exist.

Comment: @dripdrip: that is the second part with the `allow_empty`.